# Google Analytics: Events showing in real-time, but not in reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending events through Google's **[Measurement API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event)** - not the "normal" JS API.

I started sending events about **80 hours ago** (late Thursday through early Monday).

On a normal day, we send about 200-400 events. There is exactly one filter applied (filtering out a single office IP address) to the view.

**Expected behavior**: 
Events show up fine both in the real-time view as well as the reports under "Behavior".

**Observed behavior**:
Events only show up in the real-time view, but not in the reports under "Behavior".

Comment: Could you please screenshot them in real time? Do you have any applied filter under your view or account?

Comment: @F.Leone There is one filter in the view, but we tried deactivating it. We found half a solution by adding a view that filters User IDs... Now we have all the events in that view, but the rest of the data is missing

Comment: please edit your question and include the request you are sending via the measurement api i suspect you are missing a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some errors in your request data. You didn't mention params that you are sending to GA server but I had the same issue and I can tell about my experience. I was sending such parameters to GA server (PHP, using Measurement Protocol):

```
['uid' => $user->id, 't' => 'event', 'ec' => 'article', 'ea' => 'create', 'el' => 'pageview']
```

GA displayed events in real-time view but not in Behavior section. I solved my problem when I replaced 'uid' by 'cid', it wasn't a problem in my project. But I assume if you want to use 'uid' parameter you have to activate 'User-ID' function:

[image: User-ID staff in GA]